# Export Typescript interface from Angular module

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a Typescript interface `IBreadcrumbNavigation` I'm exporting. I can use it in an Angular component with `import { IBreadcrumbNavigation } from 'app/shared/interfaces/breadcrumbNavigation';`

However, the component's module already imports a `SharedModule`. I'd like to put the `IBreadcrumbNavigation` interface in the `SharedModule` so that I don't need to explicitly import it into each component that wants to use it.

In my `SharedModule` I've got

```
import { IBreadcrumbNavigation } from './interfaces/breadcrumbNavigation';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        IBreadcrumbNavigation
    ],
    exports: [
        IBreadcrumbNavigation
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { };
```

TypeScript gives the error "'IBreadcrumbNavigation' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

If I change `IBreadcrumbNavigation` from an interface to a class, the error goes away.

Is there a good fix to this, or do I just need to explicitly import the interface directly into each component?

Comment: can we see the component module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a good fix to this,

Like the error messages say, interfaces don't actually declare anything that exists at runtime. They exist purely at compile-time for TypeScript and are erased away. So it doesn't make sense to put them in an array for a decorator, since those *do* exist at runtime.

It sounds like converting to a class is what would fix it, but it's likely that you should be exporting the concrete implementers of these interfaces.

[From the docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq):

> Add [declarable](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#q-declarable) **classes
>    — components, directives, and pipes —** to a `declarations` list.
>
> Declare these classes in *exactly* one module of the application. Declare them in *this* module if they *belong* to this module.

---

> do I just need to explicitly import the interface directly into each component?

You do need to do this - keep in mind that NgModule doesn't automatically import other ECMAScript/TypeScript modules for you. Outside of templates, you'll have to take care of this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If it is not a component, pipe, directive, module,  you only import the interface in the module that you want. The interface must be exported

in  './interfaces/breadcrumbNavigation';

```
export interface IBreadcrumbNavigation {
   ...
}
```

In x component from other module you only import the interface

```
import { IBreadcrumbNavigation } from 'pathToOtherModule/interfaces/breadcrumbNavigation';
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible as they exist in runtime, one workaround is to export IBreadcrumbNavigation instead of Import

```
export{ IBreadcrumbNavigation } from './interfaces/breadcrumbNavigation';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        IBreadcrumbNavigation
    ],
    exports: [
        IBreadcrumbNavigation
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { };
```

then create a public api file to access it like this

```
export * from './lib/SharedModule ';
```

then on the component you may do like this

```
import {IBreadcrumbNavigation } from 'publicApi';
```